# Scrapy for mac ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '${project_name}'

Tags: scrapy

```
MacBookPro:~ mac$ Scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/Scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 110, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 292, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '${project_name}'
MacBookPro:~ mac$
```

I want to run Scrapy on Mac, but this problem has been bothering me for a long time and has never been solved.

I tried it

1, reinstall Python3.x and upgrade pip.

2, xcode-select --install

3, use virtualenv to create a new environment.

4, use anaconda3 to create a new environment.

But this problem can not be solved because I updated the macOS 10.14.1?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try with Python 3.6, scrapy might not be fully ready for Python 3.7. Also, try without the anaconda distribution, with a standard Python distribution to see if that helps